# Joda Period Formatter

Tags: java, jodatime, periodformatter

```
System.out.println( PeriodFormat.getDefault().print(Period.hours(1).plusMinutes(30).plusSeconds(60)));
```

The output from the above Joda PeriodFormatter is "1 hour, 30 minutes and 60 seconds".

I know that this is a fringe case, but is there a way to output this as "1 hour and 31 minutes"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could normalize it first with [`normalizedStandard`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Period.html#normalizedStandard%28%29):

```
Period period = Period.hours(1).plusMinutes(30).plusSeconds(60);
PeriodFormat.getDefault().print(period.normalizedStandard());
```

Or possibly:

```
Period period = Period.hours(1).plusMinutes(30).plusSeconds(60);
PeriodFormat.getDefault()
            .print(period.normalizedStandard(period.getPeriodType()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `toStandardDuration()`:

```
System.out.println( PeriodFormat.getDefault().print(Period.hours(1).plusMinutes(30).plusSeconds(60).toStandardDuration()));
```

Comment: javadoc for toStandardDuration() says "If the period contains years or months, an exception will be thrown.", so I'm accepting Jon Skeet's answer.
Thanks!